# Oracle inserting row from xls into database gives ORA-12899: value too large for column "AFSWEB"."BD_VEHICLES_TEMP_1"."DIVI"

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, apache-poi, poi-hssf

I have a table

```
create table BD_VEHICLES_TEMP_1
(
  CONTRACT_NO           VARCHAR2(16) not null,
  ELIMINATED_FLG        VARCHAR2(1),
  ELIMINATION_CODE      VARCHAR2(2),
  PUBLISHED             VARCHAR2(1),
  BD_GRP_ID             VARCHAR2(10),
  EMD                   NUMBER(8),
  VALUATION_PRICE       NUMBER(8),
  DIVI                  VARCHAR2(2),
)
```

I have made a corresponding bean

and setting the value of its attribute as

```
bean.setDIVI(row.getCell(27).getNumericCellValue()+"");
```

however while inserting the bean into database i get the following error

```
ORA-12899: value too large for column "AFSWEB"."BD_VEHICLES_TEMP_1"."DIVI" (actual: 4, maximum: 2)
```

I know that this has something to do with size of column.  Data in excel sheet for DIVI is 11,13,45,67.. and so on all 2 digits.

What can be the reason ? What is the solution ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Cell.getNumericCell() javadocs](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getNumericCellValue%28%29) you'll see that it returns a `double`. You appear to be trying to use a rather odd technique to turn that into a string, and your chosen way of `double+""` is very likely to produce long strings, as a double will often have lots of digits after the decimal point!

From your table definition:

```
DIVI                  VARCHAR2(2),
```

I gather that you're trying to turn the numeric cell into a two digit string. I'm not sure why you want to do that, rather than storing an `INTEGER` in your database, but I'm hoping you have a good reason.... Assuming so, you should do something with [DataFormatter](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) like

```
DataFormatter fmt = new DataFormatter();
String divi = fmt.formatCellValue(row.getCell(27).getNumericCellValue());
if (divi.length() > 2) {
   throw new IllegalStateException("Row should contain a 2 digit number, found " + divi);
}
bean.setDIVI(divi);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to print the assigned value, so you can see, what is passed to database:

```
String value = row.getCell(27).getNumericCellValue()+""; 
// or Integer.toString(row.getCell(27).getNumericCellValue()) 
System.out.println("'" + value + "'");
```

Show your JDBC statement as well.

Could it be related to Unicode? UTF16 will double length of your string.